# How to override a parent class's method but allow optional arguments?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have:

```
class A{
    public void foo(String str){
       //do stuff
    }
}
```

And also:

```
class B{
    @Override
    public void foo(String str, Integer... i){
       //do different stuff
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without doing?:

```
class B{
    public void bar(String str, Integer... i){
       //do different stuff

    @Override
    public void foo(String str){
       if(something)
          bar(str, 1);
       else if(something else)
          super.foo(str);
    }
}
```

Basically: Is it possible to override a parent method while allowing optional parameters, or does this fundamentally change the signature of `foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding optional parameters changes the signature of the method, thus preventing the override. The `@Override` attribute in your code sample is not valid.

You can find details on this in JLS section 8.4.2:

> The signature of a method `m1` is a subsignature of the signature of a method `m2` if
>   either:
>
> - `m2` has the same signature as `m1`, or
> - the signature of `m1` is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of `m2`.
>
> Two method signatures `m1` and `m2` are override-equivalent iff either `m1` is a subsignature of `m2`, or `m2` is a subsignature of `m1`.

You need to define a different method with the signature that takes an optional parameter, and call the base method through a reference to `super`.

Comment: But see Eran's answer and my comments. It's possible to have one method with identical signature overriding and an additional method with the extra parameters `Integer...i` as an overloaded method in the subclass.

Comment: @laune That is a correct observation. However, you correctly said that it would be an overload, not an override: a call to `foo(xyz)` will be delivered to `foo` in the base class if you access `B` through a variable of type `A`, which is not what OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: This isn't true. B's foo(String x) will be called even if you have `A x = new B(); x.foo("one");` Note that there are *two* foo's in B.

Comment: @laune I was talking about OP's suggestion, not Eran's answer. OP wanted to override using a method with an additional parameter, not touching the method with the original signature.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override the method if the signature doesn't match.

Here's what I would do :

```
class B
{
    public void foo (String str, Integer... i)
    {
       // executed if i.length > 0
    }

    @Override
    public void foo (String str)
    {
       // call super.foo(str) if you wish
       // and/or do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You might even rename B.bar as B.foo, avoiding the necessity of the if in (what was) bar.

Comment: And now please remove the if in the first foo